# Tuple list from dict in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key-value

How can I obtain a list of key-value tuples from a [dict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) in Python?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

For Python 2.x only (thanks Alex):

```
yourdict = {}
# ...
items = yourdict.items()
```

See http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items for details.

For Python 3.x only (taken from [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296042/tuple-list-from-dict-in-python/1296074#1296074)):

```
yourdict = {}
# ...
items = list(yourdict.items())
```

Comment: Yep, the obvious way in Python 2.*.

Answer (score 9):

For a list of of tuples:

```
my_dict.items()
```

If all you're doing is iterating over the items, however, it is often preferable to use `dict.iteritems()`, which is more memory efficient because it returns only one item at a time, rather than all items at once:

```
for key,value in my_dict.iteritems():
     #do stuff
```

Comment: the for loop could be used to make a list comprehension or a generator.

Answer (score 6):

In Python `2.*`, `thedict.items()`, as in @Andrew's answer. In Python `3.*`, `list(thedict.items())` (since there `items` is just an iterable view, not a list, you need to call `list` on it explicitly if you need exactly a list).

Comment: Meh, I'm not sure I like that... thanks for the tip, though.

Comment: @Andrew - he's basically that in Python 3+, the behavior of dict.items(), will be changing to match the behavior of dict.iteritems(), as I described them in my post.

Comment: @Triptych I was just grumbling that they chose to make the iterator the default view.

Comment: Andrew, I think that choice just reflects the fact that the iterator is what you want most of the time.

Comment: @Andrew, benhoyt is right -- the vast majority of uses are just looping, and making a list explicitly in the rare cases where you do need a list is a very Pythonic approach after all!-)

Answer (score 6):

Converting from `dict` to `list` is made easy in Python. Three examples:

```
d = {'a': 'Arthur', 'b': 'Belling'}

d.items() [('a', 'Arthur'), ('b', 'Belling')]

d.keys() ['a', 'b']

d.values() ['Arthur', 'Belling']
```

as seen in a previous answer, [Converting Python Dictionary to List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679384/converting-python-dictionary-to-list).

Answer (score -2):

For Python > 2.5:

```
a = {'1' : 10, '2' : 20 }
list(a.itervalues())
```

Comment: that's a flat list of values, not the list of (key, value) tuples the poster was asking for