# Converting Dictionary to List?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to convert a Python dictionary into a Python list, in order to perform some calculations.

```
#My dictionary
dict = {}
dict['Capital']="London"
dict['Food']="Fish&Chips"
dict['2012']="Olympics"

#lists
temp = []
dictList = []

#My attempt:
for key, value in dict.iteritems():
    aKey = key
    aValue = value
    temp.append(aKey)
    temp.append(aValue)
    dictList.append(temp) 
    aKey = ""
    aValue = ""
```

That's my attempt at it... but I can't work out what's wrong?

Comment: `sum(dict.items(), ())`

Comment: Note that in Python 3, `dict.items()` `dict.keys()` and `dict.values()` returns a `Dictionary object` which, not supporting indexing, is not a real list. A real list can be obtained by `list(dict.values())`.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Your problem is that you have `key` and `value` in quotes making them strings, i.e. you're setting `aKey` to contain the string `"key"` and not the value of the variable `key`.  Also, you're not clearing out the `temp` list, so you're adding to it each time, instead of just having two items in it.

To fix your code, try something like:

```
for key, value in dict.iteritems():
    temp = [key,value]
    dictlist.append(temp)
```

You don't need to copy the loop variables `key` and `value` into another variable before using them so I dropped them out.  Similarly, you don't need to use append to build up a list, you can just specify it between square brackets as shown above.  And we could have done `dictlist.append([key,value])` if we wanted to be as brief as possible.

Or just use `dict.items()` as has been suggested.

Comment: Correct answer due to explaining what I was doing wrong. As you can tell, I'm fairly knew to Python and any explanations are greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: If you use append lists like this, you are producing an list of lists.  What he wanted was a flat list, for which you would use extend() like in Shay's answer.

Comment: He never said that, Ajith. A list of lists is a valid python list, and a much better interpretation of a "dictionary" than a flat list containing only non-list values. A list of lists is at least capable of showing keys and values still grouped together.

Comment: It says `'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'` Can you update the answer for python 3.6 please.

Comment: `dict(iterable) -> new` dictionary initialized as if via:
        `d = {}
        for k, v in iterable:
            d[k] = v`  so please use `items()` instead of `'iteritems'`

Comment: Hi As @Trect said it is error so to avoid is use dict.items(),Like this and it would work                                           dictlist=[]

    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        temp = [key,value]
        dictlist.append(temp)

    print(dictlist)

Comment: Python 3  dict.iteritems -> dict.items.

Answer (score 557):

```
dict.items()
```

Does the trick.

(For Python 2 only)

Comment: I knew there'd be some ridiculous Pythonic way of doing this, thank you very much indeed. I just find the documentation for Python rather hard to read!

Comment: You can always use *help(dict)* on the Python command line and replace *dict* with the troublesome object to see a list of its helper methods etc., e.g. *items(...)
    D.items() -> list of D's (key, value) pairs, as 2-tuples*

Comment: He wants a flat list, items() produces a list of tuples.

Comment: He never said he wanted a flat list, he only said he wanted a list. A list of tuples is a valid python list.

Comment: To get a flat list, use dict.values() instead.

Comment: When I tried to access the list resulting from `dictlist=dict.items()`, I then got an error trying to access it like a list:  dictlist[i][1].
Python3 doc says: ~~~~ "The objects returned by dict.keys(), dict.values() and dict.items() are view objects. They provide a dynamic view on the dictionary’s entries, which means that when the dictionary changes, the view reflects these changes." ~~~~   One more step was required to make it work: ---- [ (item[0],item[1]) for item in dict.items() ]

Comment: For python3 use `list(dict.values())`

Comment: dict.items() does not return a list. Running this code: ```mydict = {'value1':['a','b','c'],'value2':['a','b','c']}
mylist= mydict.items()
print(type(mylist))```
prints out the value: ```<class 'dict_items'>```.

Comment: @JeffGruenbaum Read the comment right above yours

Answer (score 279):

Converting from [dict](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) to list is made easy in Python. Three examples:

```
>> d = {'a': 'Arthur', 'b': 'Belling'}

>> d.items()
[('a', 'Arthur'), ('b', 'Belling')]

>> d.keys()
['a', 'b']

>> d.values()
['Arthur', 'Belling']
```

Comment: Is it possible to specify the order of `values()`? Is the order of the values of a standard dict even defined?

Comment: @MichaelScheper [The order of standard dict is not specified](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9001529/638546) and the order of values can be in different from insertion order. However, one could [sort the lists above](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) or use **OrderedDict** (see the first link).

Comment: It seems that in Python3, you must use list(d.items()), list(d.keys()) and list(d.values())

Comment: I always seem to end up with dict_values at the start of each row of the list.

Comment: @MichaelScheper dictionaries don't have a stable ordering, if you want to order by keys then use ``[v for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda pair: pair[0])]``. It's a shame Python doesn't have tuple unpacking for lambdas

Comment: In Python3 dict.items(), dict.keys() and dict.values() actually return [dictionary views](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) instead of lists. Dictionary views change dynamically with the dict itself, and comparison operators can have unexpected behaviour. If you want a list, do as @MACE suggests.

Answer (score 80):

You should use `dict.items()`.

Here is a one liner solution for your problem:

```
[(k,v) for k,v in dict.items()]
```

and result:

```
[('Food', 'Fish&Chips'), ('2012', 'Olympics'), ('Capital', 'London')]
```

or you can do

```
l=[]
[l.extend([k,v]) for k,v in dict.items()]
```

for:

```
['Food', 'Fish&Chips', '2012', 'Olympics', 'Capital', 'London']
```

Comment: In python 2.6, at least, you do not need dict.items(): `[(k,v) for k,v in dict]`.

Comment: Python3.6 - `[x for x in dict.items()]` does the same thing.

Comment: or just `list(dict.items())`

Answer (score 46):

```
 >>> a = {'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 'quux', 'hello': 'world'}
 >>> list(reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, a.items()))
 ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'quux', 'hello', 'world']
```

To explain: a.items() returns a list of tuples. Adding two tuples together makes one tuple containing all elements. Thus the reduction creates one tuple containing all keys and values and then the list(...) makes a list from that.

Comment: Interesting... There could be use for this kind of merge somewhere.

Comment: For python 3.^ instead of using reduce, use functools.reduce

Answer (score 30):

Probably you just want this:

```
dictList = dict.items()
```

Your approach has two problems. For one you use `key` and `value` in quotes, which are strings with the letters "key" and "value", not related to the variables of that names. Also you keep adding elements to the "temporary" list and never get rid of old elements that are already in it from previous iterations. Make sure you have a new and empty `temp` list in each iteration and use the `key` and `value` variables:

```
for key, value in dict.iteritems():
    temp = []
    aKey = key
    aValue = value
    temp.append(aKey)
    temp.append(aValue)
    dictList.append(temp)
```

Also note that this could be written shorter without the temporary variables (and in Python 3 with `items()` instead of `iteritems()`):

```
for key, value in dict.items():
    dictList.append([key, value])
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're making a dictionary only to make a list of tuples, as creating dicts like you are may be a pain, you might look into using zip()

Its especialy useful if you've got one heading, and multiple rows. For instance if I assume that you want Olympics stats for countries:

```
headers = ['Capital', 'Food', 'Year']
countries = [
    ['London', 'Fish & Chips', '2012'],
    ['Beijing', 'Noodles', '2008'],
]

for olympics in countries:
    print zip(headers, olympics)
```

gives

```
[('Capital', 'London'), ('Food', 'Fish & Chips'), ('Year', '2012')]
[('Capital', 'Beijing'), ('Food', 'Noodles'), ('Year', '2008')]
```

Don't know if thats the end goal, and my be off topic, but it could be something to keep in mind.