# how to get all keys&values in nested dict of list-of-dicts and dicts?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
{'action_name':'mobile signup',
    'functions':[{'name':'test_signUp',
                  'parameters':{'username':'max@getappcard.com',
                                'password':'12345',
                                'mobileLater':'123454231',
                                'mobile':'1e2w1e2w',
                                'card':'1232313',
                                'cardLater':'1234321234321'}}],
    'validations':[
            {'MOB_header':'My stores'},
            {'url':"/stores/my"}]}
```

I want to get all the keys & values of this dict as a list (out of values that they are dict or array)

print result should be like this:

```
action name = mobile signup
name = test_signUp
username : max@getappcard.com
password : 12345
mobileLater: 123454231
mobile : 1e2w1e2w
card : 1232313 
cardLater : 1234321234321
MOB_header : My stores
```

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679384/converting-python-dictionary-to-list) will help?

Comment: And what have you tried? Show us some code.

Comment: For full generality, you should use `else:` instead of `elif isinstance(value, str):`.

Comment: there is one problem here: if you have nested entries with the same key, they will overwrite each other. hopefully that's nto a problem here, but you should be aware.

Comment: known issue. my purpose is not to add to dict, but only to run function on each of the key+value and  then update the dictIn itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might want to use a recursive function to extract all the `key, value` pairs.

```
def extract(dict_in, dict_out):
    for key, value in dict_in.iteritems():
        if isinstance(value, dict): # If value itself is dictionary
            extract(value, dict_out)
        elif isinstance(value, unicode):
            # Write to dict_out
            dict_out[key] = value
    return dict_out
```

Something of this sort. I come from C++ background so I had to google for all the syntaxes.

Comment: It might be better to replace the line `elif isinstance(value, unicode):` with `else:`.

Comment: @sparkandshine IMHO explicit is better than implicit. The `isinstance` part also works as documentation.

Comment: Doesn't really work with lists (even in the author's example), does it? Have to traverse lists too.

Comment: Python 3 renamed dict.iteritems -> dict.items.

Answer (score 3):

I have modified a little bit from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39233973/get-all-keys-of-a-nested-dictionary) to get all keys&values in nested dict of list-of-dicts and dicts:

```
def recursive_items(dictionary):
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if type(value) is dict:
            yield (key, value)
            yield from recursive_items(value)
        elif type(value) is list:
            yield (key, value)
            for i in value:
                if type(i) is dict:
                    yield from recursive_items(i)
        else:
            yield (key, value)

for i in recursive_items(your_dict):
    print(i) #print out tuple of (key, value)
```

Output:

```
('action_name', 'mobile signup')
('functions', [{'name': 'test_signUp', 'parameters': {'username': 
'max@getappcard.com', 'password': '12345', 'mobileLater': '123454231', 'mobile': 
'1e2w1e2w', 'card': '1232313', 'cardLater': '1234321234321'}}])
('name', 'test_signUp')
('parameters', {'username': 'max@getappcard.com', 'password': '12345', 
'mobileLater': '123454231', 'mobile': '1e2w1e2w', 'card': '1232313', 
'cardLater': '1234321234321'})
('username', 'max@getappcard.com')
('password', '12345')
('mobileLater', '123454231')
('mobile', '1e2w1e2w')
('card', '1232313')
('cardLater', '1234321234321')
('validations', [{'MOB_header': 'My stores'}, {'url': '/stores/my'}])
('MOB_header', 'My stores')
('url', '/stores/my')
```

Answer (score 0):

a little late but for python 3.8 you can use `yield from`

```py
def dictitems2list(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        yield k
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            yield from get_all_items(v)
        else:
            yield v

all_itemt = list(dict2items(d))
```

Comment: What's the definition for `get_all_items()`?