# Looking for a key in a nested dict to change the type of the key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict like this one:

```
exampleDict={'name': 'Example1', 'code': 2, 'price': 23, 'dimensions': [2,2]}
```

And I want to change the type of `dimensions`to a string, like this:

```
exampleDict['dimensions'] = str(dict['dimensions'])
```

This works just fine. But imagine there are nested dicts inside my `exampleDict`, and `dimensions`is a bit far inside.

My guess is to do something recursively. From what I have searched in here, (examples like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756427/loop-through-all-nested-dictionary-values), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39233973/get-all-keys-of-a-nested-dictionary), they use `yield`in a recursive function, but I am not sure why it's used.

I was thinking on doing this:

```
def changeToStringDim(d):
    if 'dimensions' in d:
        d['dimensiones'] = str(d['dimensions'])
    for k in d:
        if isinstance(d[k], list):
            for i in d[k]:
                for j in changeToStringDim(i):
                    j[dimensions] = str(j['dimensions'])
```

I found it in here, but instead of the assignment of `j[dimensions]=str(j['dimensions'])` it did a `yield`.But I adapted the solution to this, and it works fine in a dict like this example.

Now I am trying to do it in a nested one.

```
exDict2={'name': 'example1',
         'nesting': {'subnesting1': 'sub2',
                     'coordinates': [41.6769705, 2.288154]},
         'price': 123123132}
         }
```

With the same function but changing it to coordinates:

```
def changeToStringCoord(d):
    if 'coordinates' in d:
        d['coordinates'] = str(d['coordinates'])
    for k in d:
        if isinstance(d[k], list):
            for i in d[k]:
                for j in changeToStringDim(i):
                    j['coordinates'] = str(j['coordinates'])
```

And it won't do anything. I have debugged it, and it will just go through `name`, `nesting`and  `price`. The `isinstance`is not working properly (or it is and I am not fully understanding its methodology).

Comment: Why not just something like `d[k] = str(d[k])`? Show your desired output, because at the moment your description is confusing.

Comment: Sure, I will edit the question right away. But not like this because I can receive a dict from parameter. It can have `coordinates` in a plain dict, or it can be nested. So I do not know what dict I get! Only that I need to change that! @meowgoesthedog

Comment: Well to deal with nesting you should call `changeToStringDim` recursively if `isinstance(d[k], dict) == True`, just as the code is doing with `list`.

Comment: Yes, but it is not working. Changing `dict`will cause an error in `string indeces must be integers`in `isinstance(d[k], dict)` @meowgoesthedog

Comment: The isinstance needs to take a type, be it `list`, `dict`, etc. I am not overriding anything! It needs to take a type! @meowgoesthedog

Comment: You probably misunderstood my comment and changed the wrong piece of code. I'll upload a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code with comments:

```
def changeNestedListToString(d):
    for k in d:

        # recursive call on dictionary type
        if isinstance(d[k], dict):
            changeNestedListToString(d[k])

        # convert lists to string
        elif isinstance(d[k], list):
            d[k] = str(d[k])

        # leave everything else untouched
```

Test data:

```
example = {
    'name': 'example1',
    'nesting': {
        'subnesting1': 'sub2',
        'coordinates': [41.6769705, 2.288154]
    },
    'price': 123123132
}
```

After calling the function:

```
{
    'price': 123123132, 
    'name': 'example1', 
    'nesting': {
         'coordinates': '[41.6769705, 2.288154]', 
         'subnesting1': 'sub2'
    }
}
```

As you can see `'coordinates'` has been converted to a string while everything else was left untouched.

Comment: How is coordinates being changed, and not anything else, if in the function, the worth `'coordinates'`does not appear! It is working though!

Comment: @M.K it just converts all values of type `list` to strings. If you only want specific keys to be changed you should pass a list of said keys.

Comment: That is even better than what I wanted actually. All types of list to strings is perfect! Thank you!