# Print out all objects with keys and values

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project that requires me to print out all objects, I have to use nested for in loops.

The result should be printed like this:

```
team: Manchester United 
stadium:
   name:The Valley
   capacity:65000  
league: League 1
kit:
   home: blue and white
   away:light blue`
```

Here's what I came up with:

```
function footballClub() {
let club = {
    team: "Manchester United",
    stadium: {
        name: "The Valley",
        capacity: 65000
    },
    league: "League1",
    kit: {
        home: "blue and white",
        away: "light blue"
    }
}

    for (let outerKey in club) {
        for (let innerKey in club[outerKey]) {
            if (typeof club[outerKey === club.stadium.hasOwnProperty('name')]) {
                console.log(outerKey + ": " + innerKey + ": " + club[outerKey].name);
            }
            console.log(outerKey + ": " + club[outerKey]);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm stuck because it just repeats the team, stadium etc. 8 times because of the outer and inner loops.

I can't seem to print each inner objects as it always prints the `name`, I've tried adding `capacity`, `home`, and `away` but it never prints them, so I have to remove them from the code.

Is there a way to print all outer objects and inner objects dynamically and without repeating itself 8 times?

Comment: This post might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all keys of a nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39233973/get-all-keys-of-a-nested-dictionary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slight changes to code. Just check value is object or not before navigating in inner loop. Problem in current code is `for in` loop is going over string value.

```js
function footballClub() {
  let club = {
    team: "Manchester United",
    stadium: {
      name: "The Valley",
      capacity: 65000
    },
    league: "League1",
    kit: {
      home: "blue and white",
      away: "light blue"
    }
  };

  for (let outerKey in club) {
    if (typeof club[outerKey] !== "string") {
      for (let innerKey in club[outerKey]) {
        console.log(
          outerKey + ": " + innerKey + ": " + club[outerKey][innerKey]
        );
      }
      console.log('');
    } else {
        console.log(outerKey + ": " + club[outerKey]);
        console.log('');
    }
  }
}

footballClub();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const
  club = {
    team: 'Manchester United',
    stadium: {
      name: 'The Valley',
      capacity: 65000
    },
    league: 'League1',
    kit: {
      home: 'blue and white',
      away: 'light blue'
    }
  },
  result = Object.entries(club).map(([key, value]) =>
    key + ': ' + (typeof value === 'string' ?
      value :
      Object.entries(value).map(([innerKey, innerValue]) =>
        `\n\t${innerKey}: ${innerValue}`).join(''))
  ).join('\n');
  
console.log(result)
```