# Search in different type of list of dictionary by keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am requesting data from different APIs. All of them provide similar information but output they provide is a little bit different with regard to the structure. Every output is contained in list of dictionary but with different organisation and structure. One output can be a list with just one dictionary, other more than one dictionary and also dictionary as value of another dictionary.

Here I show one example output

```
[{'allele_string': 'G/A',
 'transcript_consequences': [{'protein_end': 663,
   'gene_symbol_source': 'HGNC',
   'protein_start': 663,
   'gene_symbol': 'MYH7',
   'amino_acids': 'R/H',
   'codons': 'cGc/cAc',
   'biotype': 'protein_coding',
   'hgnc_id': 'HGNC:7577',
   'cds_end': 1988,
   'cds_start': 1988,
   'polyphen_score': 0.782,
   'transcript_id': 'ENST00000355349',
   'cdna_start': 2093,
   'impact': 'MODERATE',
   'consequence_terms': ['missense_variant'],
   'variant_allele': 'A',
   'cdna_end': 2093,
   'sift_score': 0.06,
   'gene_id': 'ENSG00000092054',
   'sift_prediction': 'tolerated',
   'polyphen_prediction': 'possibly_damaging',
   'strand': -1}],
 'input': 'NM_000257.3:c.1988G>A',
 'start': 23426833,
 'end': 23426833,
 'colocated_variants': [{'phenotype_or_disease': 1,
   'allele_string': 'HGMD_MUTATION',
   'strand': 1,
   'id': 'CM993620',
   'seq_region_name': '14',
   'end': 23426833,
   'start': 23426833},
  {'allele_string': 'C/T',
...
```

Independently of the structure of the list of dictionaries, I need to get for example the value of the key 'gene_symbol' and 'allele_string'. These values can be in the first dictionary of the list or in the last one or in a dictionary inside another dictionary. So I think that what I need is to read key by key of the complete list and find the key I am looking for and then save its value in one variable for example

```
gene_symbol = 'value_found'
```

Is this the best approach to do this? and How can I do that?

Comment: Check here for some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39233973/get-all-keys-of-a-nested-dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use some complex function, possibly using recursion to get all keys-values from your structure. This is more elegant but more difficult as well.
See here for some ideas:

[Get all keys of a nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39233973/get-all-keys-of-a-nested-dictionary)

Another approach is to handle your structure as a text. If your result is always pretty similar, like 'gene_symbol': 'MYH7', inside your structure, you can use something like the following (result is based on the structure you provided):

```
s=str(your_structure)

s2=s[s.find("'gene_symbol'")+13:] #13 is the length of "'gene_symbol'"
s3=s2[s2.find("'")+1:]
res=s3[:s3.find("',")]

>>> res
'MYH7'
```

Similarly for 'allele_string':

```
s2=s[s.find("'allele_string'")+15:] #15 is the length of "'allele_string'"
s3=s2[s2.find("'")+1:]
res=s3[:s3.find("',")]

>>> res
'G/A'
```

You can easily adjust your code if results may vary slightly

Answer (score 0):

We can also use Regex for this as shown below:

```
import re

s = str(your_api_response)
search_key = 'your search key'

regex = "'"+search_key+r"':\s(.+?)[,\}\]\)]"

pattern_obj = re.compile(regex)
match = pattern_obj.search(s)

if match:
    print(match.group(1))
else:
    print('No matching key found.')
```

Breaking down the Regex:

- `(.+?)` - It will match all the characters except a newline until the first occurrence of the next character in regex i.e., here `[,\}\]\)]`
- `[,\}\]\)]` - It will match either `,` or `}` or `]` or `)`. I have added these brackets to handle the case where the search_key is last element in a list, tuple, or a dict.