# Select the second specific string if found more than one in a string variable

Tags: python, string

I am requesting data from `Ensembl API` and (because I do not how to do in a more pythonic way) I transform the output in a string to get later the datum I want.

Here is one example output

```
"{'id': 'NM_000138.4:c.356G>A', 'seq_region_name': '15', 'start': 48600225, 'end': 48600225, 'colocated_variants': [{'allele_string': 'C/T', 'strand': 1, 'seq_region_name': '15', 'id': 'rs111604463', 'start': 48600225, 'end': 48600225}], 'most_severe_consequence': 'missense_variant', 'strand': -1, 'assembly_name': 'GRCh38', 'allele_string': 'G/A', 'regulatory_feature_consequences': [{'biotype': 'promoter_flanking_region', 'regulatory_feature_id': 'ENSR00000992369', 'variant_allele': 'A', 'consequence_terms': ['regulatory_region_variant'], 'impact': 'MODIFIER'}], 'transcript_consequences': [{'cds_start': 356, 'polyphen_score': 0.991, 'cdna_start': 672, 'transcript_id': 'ENST00000316623', 'variant_allele': 'A', 'consequence_terms': ['missense_variant'], 'cdna_end': 672, 'impact': 'MODERATE', 'sift_prediction': 'deleterious', 'gene_id': 'ENSG00000166147', 'sift_score': 0, 'strand': -1, 'polyphen_prediction': 'probably_damaging', 'gene_symbol_source': 'HGNC', 'protein_end': 119, 'gene_symbol': 'FBN1', 'protein_start': 119, 'amino_acids': 'C/Y', 'codons': 'tGc/tAc', 'biotype': 'protein_coding', 'cds_end': 356, 'hgnc_id': 'HGNC:3603'}, {'consequence_terms': ['missense_variant', 'NMD_transcript_variant'], 'variant_allele': 'A', 'cdna_end': 672, 'impact': 'MODERATE', 'sift_prediction': 'deleterious', 'gene_id': 'ENSG00000166147', 'sift_score': 0, 'strand': -1, 'polyphen_prediction': 'probably_damaging', 'cds_start': 356, 'polyphen_score': 1, 'cdna_start': 672, 'transcript_id': 'ENST00000537463', 'amino_acids': 'C/Y', 'codons': 'tGc/tAc', 'biotype': 'nonsense_mediated_decay', 'cds_end': 356, 'hgnc_id': 'HGNC:3603', 'protein_end': 119, 'gene_symbol_source': 'HGNC', 'protein_start': 119, 'gene_symbol': 'FBN1'}], 'input': 'NM_000138.4:c.356G>A'}"
```

For example if I want to get the value contained in the key `allele_string` I just do this

```
REF=s[s.find("'allele_string'")+15:] 
REF2=REF[REF.find("'")+1:]
REF3=REF2[:REF2.find("/")]

Print(REF3)
'C/T'
```

This code is taken from
[Search in different type of list of dictionary by keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65322725/search-in-different-type-of-list-of-dictionary-by-keys)

This approach has been working quite well but for one reason I can't explain with regard to `allele_string` sometimes not always. I found out that there are two keys called `allele_string`. If there is only one `allele_string` in the output, that datum is what I need. However, if there are two keys called `allele_string` I need the second. The problem is that my code always select the first.

How could I produce an `if-condition` or something that identifies if there are one or more than one 'allele_string' and in case of more than 1 select the second, if no more than one select the first?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.  The documentation on string operations includes `rfind`.

Comment: What library do you use to get the data from Ensembl API?

Comment: Have you tried importing the string as json? `import json; json.loads(your_string)`