# Python, get dictionary, nested dictionary, nested list keys

Tags: python, json, key

I am trying to get all keys from a json file in Python.
How to get nested second level(x,y) and third level keys(a,b).
For example, Keys: results,x,y,a,b

Code:

```
#open data
import json

with open('list.json') as f:
    my_dict = json.load(f)

#1
    #find keys
    for key in my_dict.keys():
         print("Keys : {}".format(key))
```

Json:

```
{
   "results":[
      {
         "x":5
      },
      {
         "x":5,
         "y":[
            1,
            2,
            3
         ]
      },
      {
         "x":5,
         "y":{
            "a":2,
            "b":67
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Output:

```
Keys : results
```

Answer (score 0):

Use recursive function to return all nested keys. Here is the reference [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39233973/get-all-keys-of-a-nested-dictionary) page.

```
import json

def recursive_items(dictionary):
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if type(value) is list:
            for i in value:
                if type(i) is dict:
                    yield from recursive_items(i)
        else:
            yield key

with open('list.json') as f:
    my_dict = json.load(f)

    #find keys
    for key in recursive_items(my_dict):
         print("Keys : {}".format(key))
```

Comment: I still get only the "results" key

Comment: I see, since the value of 'results' key in your dictionary is list, the above code will not work properly. @NoemonGR edited answers, check it out now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the keys which are a part of the value of the JSON.

You therefore need to iterate over the values of `my_dict` not the keys.

Comment: with value I get everything Output: (results[{'x': 5}, {'x': 5, 'y': [1, 2, 3]}, {'x': 5, 'y': {'a': 2, 'b': 67}}])