# Get all the keys of a nested dict

Tags: python

With xmltodict I managed to get my code from xml in a dict and now I want to create an excel.
In this excel the header of a value is going to be all the parents (keys in the dict).
For example:

```
dict = {"name":"Pete", "last-name": "Pencil", "adres":{"street": "example1street", "number":"5", "roommate":{"gender":"male"}}}
```

The value male will have the header: adres/roommate/gender.

Comment: I think you were looking for it in a wrong way. Dict in a dict is equal to nested dict. So within stackoverflow you've got a post talking about it: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39233973/get-all-keys-of-a-nested-dictionary)

Comment: Could you write out what your expected output is?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to orgainze the data in the way your question asks:

```py
d = {"name":"Pete", "last-name": "Pencil", "adres":{"street": "example1street", "number":"5", "roommate":{"gender":"male"}}}
print(d)
stack = [('', d)]
headerByValue = {}
while stack:
    name, top = stack.pop()
    if isinstance(top, dict):
        stack += (((name + '/' if name else '') + k, v) for k, v in top.items())
    else:
        headerByValue[name] = top

print(headerByValue)
```

Output:

```
{'adres/roommate/gender': 'male', 
'adres/number': '5', 
'adres/street': 'example1street', 
'last-name': 'Pencil', 
'name': 'Pete'}
```

Comment: Do you need any additional help with your question?