# How to convert a dict key's values into a list in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
myDict = {'Fruits': ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Bananas'], 'Meats': ['Beef', 'Chicken', 'Pork']}
myDict2 = {'FoodType1': ['Fruits'], 'FoodType2': ['Meats']}
```

What I am trying to do is this:

```
food = myDict2.get('FoodType1')
if 'Oranges' in myDict.get(food):
   return "True!"
```

I know the issue is that the variable 'food' is ['Fruits'], which is a mutable list. Is there a better way to do the if check if I must use those two dicts?

I add to `myDict2` using `myDict2.append()` and it looks to be adding them as lists. How can I add them as strings?

Comment: Have you had a look at this? :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679384/converting-python-dictionary-to-list

Comment: Your attempt is correct na ? `myDict = {'Fruits': ['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas'], 'Meat': ['beef', 'chicken']}`

Comment: That's not even valid Python syntax. You are missing the curly braces.

Comment: I revised my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your dict with curly braces

```
myDict = {'Fruits': ['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas'], 'Meat': ['beef', 'chicken']}
if 'apples' in myDict['Fruits']:
     print 'Here'
```

Comment: Oh, this explains everything - `TypeError` usually appears when the syntax is invalid, hence the name.

Comment: No.  `SyntaxError` is what you get for invalid syntax -- which is your first line of code gives.  I'm not sure how you got a `TypeError`.  I presume the code you posted in your question is not the code you are using.