# How do I convert this dictionary into a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Say I have dictionaries like this :

```
{'AccountNum': '873627867348', 'userID': 'abc'}
{'AccountNum': '873627867348', 'userID': 'def'}
{'AccountNum': '038683828978', 'userID': 'ghi'}
{'AccountNum': '581889263266', 'userID': 'jkl'}
{'AccountNum': '581889263266', 'userID': 'mno'}
{'AccountNum': '581889263266', 'userID': 'pqr'}
```

I need to convert this into a `list` such that both the keys and values are printed. Actually I am using Django as the web framework. I need to return a list and render it to my template page, where I will be displaying the user id and accountnum in the rows of the table.

**preferred output sample:**

```
['AccountNum', '873627867348', 'userID', 'abc']
```

Comment: What is your list supposed to look like?

Comment: When I tried converting the above dict into list.. I got an output like this :   ['AccountNum', 'userID']  ..but I don't see any values here

Comment: Maybe list with tuples is the only way to get both keys and values ?

Comment: list(d.items())

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Python Dictionary to List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679384/converting-python-dictionary-to-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the keys as list, use:

```
list( {'AccountNum': '873627867348', 'userID': 'abc'} )
#['AccountNum', 'userID']
```

for the values:

```
list( v for k, v in {'AccountNum': '873627867348', 'userID': 'abc'}.items() )
#['873627867348', 'abc']
```

for both:

```
list( {'AccountNum': '873627867348', 'userID': 'abc'}.items() )
#[('AccountNum', '873627867348'), ('userID', 'abc')]
```

if you don't like it with tuple here an approach with more then one line:

```
def dictToList(d):
    l = []
    for k, v in  d.items():
        l.append(k)
        l.append(v)
    return l
dictToList({'AccountNum': '873627867348', 'userID': 'abc'})
# ['AccountNum', '873627867348', 'userID', 'abc']
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer .. The last one was what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

How about this using list comprehension:

```
[a for a in(b for a in data.items() for b in a)]
```

Input :

```
data={'AccountNum': '873627867348', 'userID': 'abc'}
```

Output :

```
['userID', 'abc', 'AccountNum', '873627867348']
```

You can also use Regular expression,

```
import re
data={'AccountNum': '873627867348', 'userID': 'abc'}

re.findall(r"\'(.*?)\'", str(data) )
```

Output :

```
['userID', 'abc', 'AccountNum', '873627867348']
```