# Converting a dictionary of dictionaries to a List of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary of dictionaries.Is there any possible way to convert it to a list of dictionaries?
And if not, then how is the filter() method applied to filter data in a dictionary of dictionaries?

```js
{"0": {"_ref": "ipam:stat/ZGkMTAuMTQ4LjEyLjAvMjIvMA:default/10.158.2.0/22",
"comment": "VLAN 0",
"dhcp_utilization": 0,
"disable": false,
"enable_ddns": false,
"extattrs": {"CITY": {"value": "city" },
      "COUNTRY": {
        "value": "ABC"
      },
      "Helpnow ID": {
        "value": "TA"
            "value": 0
      }
    },
    "members": [],
    "network": "10.158.2.0",
    "utilization": 4
  },{"0": {"_ref": "ipam:stat/ZGkMQ4LjEyLjAvMjIvMA:default/10.109.2.0/22",
    "comment": "VLAN 0",
    "dhcp_utilization": 0,
    "disable": false,
    "enable_ddns": false,
    "extattrs": {
      "CITY": {
        "value": "city"
      },
      "COUNTRY": {
        "value": "CDS"
      },
      "Helpnow ID": {
        "value": "TA"
            "value": 0
      }
    },
    "members": [],
    "network": "10.109.2.0",
    "utilization": 9
  }]
```

Comment: `Is there any possible way to convert it to a list of dictionaries?` Yes, there is. Any other questions? How about starting with a [mcve]?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Python Dictionary to List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679384/converting-python-dictionary-to-list)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A list comprehension should do the job, no need for `filter()`.

```
>>> dic_of_dics = {1: {"a": "A"}, 2: {"b": "B"}, 3: {"c": "C"}}

>>> list_of_dics = [value for value in dic_of_dics.values()]

>>>list_of_dics
[{'a': 'A'}, {'b': 'B'}, {'c': 'C'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to mention a solution with keeping first-level "key" associated with "id" inside next level of dictionaries.

to rephrase it "Converting a dictionary of dictionaries to a List of dictionaries
with keeping key inside".

```py
>>> dic_of_dics = {1: {"a": "A"}, 2: {"b": "B"}, 3: {"c": "C"}}

>>> [(lambda d: d.update(id=key) or d)(val) for (key, val) in dic_of_dics.items()]
[{'a': 'A', 'id': 1}, {'b': 'B', 'id': 2}, {'c': 'C', 'id': 3}]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I'm aware the question is somewhat old, but just in case someone needs the solution I was looking for:

If you want to keep the keys of the outer dict without having them as a value in the inner dict, the following code produces a list of tuples `(key, dict)` for every inner dict.

```
>>> dic_of_dics = {1: {"a": "A"}, 2: {"b": "B"}, 3: {"c": "C"}}
>>> [(k,v) for k, v in dic_of_dics.items()]
[(1, {'a': 'A'}), (2, {'b': 'B'}), (3, {'c': 'C'})]
```

I used it to define a `networkx` graph through the `add_nodes_from()` function from a dict of dicts produced by the `to_dict('index')` function from `pandas` and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question very well, the task is to turn a dictionary of dictionaries into a list of dictionaries without losing the structure of the data.

A `list comprehension` would achieve this neatly where every item in the list is essentially a dictionary of a dictionary.

```
>>> dic_of_dicts = {1: {"a": "A"}, 2: {"b": "B"}, 3: {"c": "C"}}
>>> [{k: v} for k, v in dic_of_dicts.items()]
[{1: {'a': 'A'}}, {2: {'b': 'B'}}, {3: {'c': 'C'}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass a dictionary of dictionaries to `list()` is more concise and faster:

```
dic_of_dicts = {1: {"a": "A"}, 2: {"b": "B"}, 3: {"c": "C"}}
list_of_dicts = list(dic_of_dics.values())
list_of_dicts
[{'a': 'A'}, {'b': 'B'}, {'c': 'C'}]
```

Benchmark:

```
%timeit [value for value in dic_of_dics.values()]
153 ns ± 1.13 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)

%timeit list(dic_of_dics.values())
95.3 ns ± 0.639 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)
```