# Getting the accuracy from classification_report back into a list

Tags: python, scikit-learn, return

I am using Sklean's classification_report to summarize my train and test epochs.

```
sklearn.metrics.classification_report
```

I'm getting kind of this back for each epoch:

```
>>> from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
>>> y_true
>>> y_pred 
>>> target_names = ['class 0', 'class 1', 'class 2']
>>> print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred, target_names=target_names))
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

     class 0       0.50      1.00      0.67         1
     class 1       0.00      0.00      0.00         1
     class 2       1.00      0.67      0.80         3

    accuracy                           0.60         5
   macro avg       0.50      0.56      0.49         5
weighted avg       0.70      0.60      0.61         5
```

(e.g. from sklearn script)

Now I am searching for a way, to get those accuracy for each epoch in a list to calculate the mean and std of all accuracy.

This question seems to be pretty trivial but as you can see from my questions before I am pretty new to Python/Machine Learning.

Thanks for your help

Leo

Comment: Why the `PyTorch` tag?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lets have a look at the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html) which contains information about the input parameter **output_dict** :

> output_dict : bool (default = False) If True, return output as dict

If you call `classification_report(y_true, y_pred, target_names=target_names, output_dict=True)` you can get the dictionary. And then you are one stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679384/converting-dictionary-to-list) away from your solution.

Comment: This answer does not answer to the question. Please remove the answer.

Comment: @Prashant Would you like to offer a better answer? Please provide one, and then let the upvotes decide which answer helps most users.

Comment: I am still searching and looks like it is not possible with `classification_report`