# How to create a dictionary from a given list?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary from my given list, knowing that the key will be the first letter of that word, and those have the same first letter would be added up to 1 key correspondingly. Can you guys help me out, please?

```py
words= ['apple', 'bible','bird' ,'candy', 'day', 'elephant','friend']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting Dictionary to List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679384/converting-dictionary-to-list)

Comment: What do you mean by: "would be added up to 1 key correspondingly"? Could you show your expected result ?

Answer (score 6):

A more pythonic solution:

```
import collections

words= ['apple', 'bible','bird' ,'candy', 'day', 'elephant','friend']

d = collections.defaultdict(list)

for w in words:
    d[w[0]].append(w)

d = dict(d)
```

Output

```
{
    "a": ["apple"],
    "b": ["bible", "bird"],
    "c": ["candy"],
    "d": ["day"],
    "e": ["elephant"],
    "f": ["friend"],
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
words= ['apple', 'bible','bird' ,'candy', 'day', 'elephant','friend']

def make_dict(words):
    di = {}
    for item in words:
        if item[0] in di:
            di[item[0]] += [item]
        else:
            di[item[0]] = [item]
    return di
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another option:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

words = ['apple', 'bible','bird' ,'candy', 'day', 'elephant','friend']

word_dict = defaultdict(lambda: [])

list(map(lambda word: word_dict[word[0]].append(word), words))

print(dict(word_dict))
```

Results in:

```
{'a': ['apple'], 'b': ['bible', 'bird'], 'c': ['candy'], 'd': ['day'], 'e': ['elephant'], 'f': ['friend']}
```