# Make a list of first item in every element of a dictionary

Tags: python, list, loops

I am working with a dictionary from a file with an import. This is the dictionary:

```
[{'id': 76001,
  'full_name': 'Alaa Abdelnaby',
  'first_name': 'Alaa',
  'last_name': 'Abdelnaby',
  'is_active': False},
 {'id': 76002,
  'full_name': 'Zaid Abdul-Aziz',
  'first_name': 'Zaid',
  'last_name': 'Abdul-Aziz',
  'is_active': False},
 {'id': 76003,
  'full_name': 'Kareem Abdul-Jabbar',
  'first_name': 'Kareem',
  'last_name': 'Abdul-Jabbar',
  'is_active': False}]
```

What I want to do is get a list out of all the IDs:

```
player_ids = [76001,76002, 76003]
```

I have tried:

```
player_ids = []
for i in player_dict:
    player_ids.append(player_dict[i]['id'])
```

but I get the error

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict

So I get that 'i' is not the place but the actual item I am calling in the dictionary? But I'm not able to make much sense of this based on what I have read.

Comment: When you do `for i in player_dict`, `i` is each element in the list not an index.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting Dictionary to List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679384/converting-dictionary-to-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pythonic way to do this is with a list comprehension. For example:

`player_ids = [dict['id'] for dict in player_dict]`

This basically loops over all dictionaries in the player_dict, which is actually a list in your case, and for every dictionary gets the item with key 'id'.

Comment: I get the error 'TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict'
Edit: I restarted the kernel and now this works, I am unsure what caused this before, thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can try list comprehension:

```
>>> [d['id'] for d in my_list]
[76001, 76002, 76003]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can use a list comprehension:

```
player_dict = [{'id': 76001,
               'full_name': 'Alaa Abdelnaby',
               'first_name': 'Alaa',
               'last_name': 'Abdelnaby',
               'is_active': False},
              {'id': 76002,
               'full_name': 'Zaid Abdul-Aziz',
               'first_name': 'Zaid',
               'last_name': 'Abdul-Aziz',
               'is_active': False},
              {'id': 76003,
               'full_name': 'Kareem Abdul-Jabbar',
               'first_name': 'Kareem',
               'last_name': 'Abdul-Jabbar',
               'is_active': False}]

player_ids = [d['id'] for d in player_dict]

print(player_ids)
```

Output:

```
[76001, 76002, 76003]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just append

```
  player_ids.append(i['id'])
```

Comment: I would encourage you to offer more of an explanation with your answers.  Do you understand why the original problem occurred?  I'm sure you do, so share your insights.