# Efficient way to convert a dict into a flat data structure (list or tuple)

Tags: python, list, performance, dictionary, memory-efficient

I implemented a [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) for a board game. Here I use a `dict` to reflect duplicate board configurations on each level. Currently, the overall search takes nearly all the RAM I have (16GB) for one start configuration. I plan to integrate intersection checks for different start configurations. So I need read access to the configurations I found, and the dict for one level doesn't change if the level is finished.

That's why I plan to convert the `dict` into a flat data structure (`list` or `tuple`) with keys at `[2n]` position and values at `[2n+1]` position before I evaluate the next level.

The problem is to find a *fast* conversion from `{1: 2, 3: 4}` to `[1, 2, 3, 4]` for `dict`with more than `10**8` items.

I found `sum(dict.items(), ())` from [a comment by Natim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679384/converting-dictionary-to-list#comment68681318_1679384) to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1679384/2932052), which worked, but which is too slow (it seemingly stops working for `dict`s with more than 10**6 items).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `itertools` function `chain` and `classmethod` alternative constructor [`from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(dct.items()))
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
```

Or with `operator.iconcat` and `functools.reduce`:

```
>>> import operator, functools
>>> functools.reduce(operator.iconcat, dct.items(), [])
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237450/discussion-between-wolf-and-u12-forward).

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
dct = {1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8}

out = [None] * 2*len(dct)

for idx, (out[2*idx],out[2*idx+1]) in enumerate(dct.items()):
    pass

print(out)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

**Check Runtime with `dictionary` that size is `50_000_000`:** *(on [colab](http://colab.research.google.com))*

```
from timeit import timeit
import operator, functools
from itertools import chain

def approach1(dct):
    li = []
    for k, v in dct.items():
        li.extend([k,v])
    return li

def approach2(dct):
    out = [None] * 2*len(dct)
    for idx, (out[2*idx],out[2*idx+1]) in enumerate(dct.items()):
        pass
    return (out)

def approach3(dct):
    return functools.reduce(operator.iconcat, dct.items(), [])

def approach4(dct):
    return list(chain.from_iterable(dct.items()))

def approach5(dct):
    return [i for t in dct.items() for i in t]
    
funcs = approach1, approach2, approach3, approach4, approach5
dct = {i:i for i in range(50_000_000)}

for _ in range(3):
    for func in funcs:
        t = timeit(lambda: func(dct), number=1)
        print('%.3f s ' % t, func.__name__)
    print()
```

Output:

```
8.825 s  approach1
13.243 s  approach2
4.506 s  approach3
3.809 s  approach4
7.881 s  approach5

8.391 s  approach1
13.159 s  approach2
4.487 s  approach3
3.854 s  approach4
7.946 s  approach5

8.391 s  approach1
13.197 s  approach2
4.448 s  approach3
3.681 s  approach4
7.904 s  approach5
```

**Check Runtime with different size of `dictionary`:** *(on [colab](http://colab.research.google.com))*

```
from timeit import timeit
import operator, functools
from itertools import chain
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def app_extend(dct):
    li = []
    for k, v in dct.items():
        li.extend([k,v])
    return li
def app_enumerate(dct):
    out = [None] * 2*len(dct)
    for idx, (out[2*idx],out[2*idx+1]) in enumerate(dct.items()):
        pass
    return (out)
def app_functools(dct):
    return functools.reduce(operator.iconcat, dct.items(), [])
def app_chain(dct):
    return list(chain.from_iterable(dct.items()))
def app_for(dct):
    return [i for t in dct.items() for i in t]
funcs = app_extend, app_enumerate, app_functools, app_chain, app_for
dct_rslt = {}
for dct_size in [100_000, 250_000, 500_000, 1_000_000, 2_500_000, 5_000_000, 10_000_000, 25_000_000, 50_000_000]:
    dct = {i:i for i in range(dct_size)}
    dct_rslt[str(dct_size)] = {func.__name__ : timeit(lambda: func(dct), number=1) for func in funcs}
df = pd.DataFrame(dct_rslt).T
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(12, 9)
sns.lineplot(data=df)
plt.xlabel('Dictionary Size')
plt.ylabel('Time(sec)')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: ... please don't forget that it has to be fast for dicts with millions of items, maybe not easy to extrapolate ...

Comment: I changed the integer literal within `range` for better readability.

Comment: @Wolf edited answer with runtime on colab, my PC was slow ;)

Answer (score 0):

Appending and extending a `list` is quite efficient in python:

```
def dict_to_list(d):
    li = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        li.extend([k,v])
    return li
```

Therefore, the above apparently naive function beats the very compact and somehow also elegant expression `list(sum(d.items(), ()))` in terms of performance.

Comment: ``list(chain.from_iterable(a.items()))``

Comment: It's a bit sad that this first reaction didn't start as an answer. I think it's high likely that I keep the mantra *chain from iterable* in mind instead of the slightly faster functional recipe with more ingredients.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension over the items of the dict:

```
d = {1: 2, 3: 4}
print([i for t in d.items() for i in t])
```

This outputs:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: basically the same speed as the "naive function"